# Which p2p Library does Vuze use?

Tags: java, ice, stun, vuze

Which Libary does Vuze use for its p2p connection? Like JXTA, STUNT, ICE4J and so on. Or did they develop a p2p nat traversal libary by themself? If yes, can I find this p2p connection libary somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look in their [online repository](http://azureus.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/azureus/azureus2/com/aelitis/net/natpmp/).

Comment: Yes I know, that is the reason for my question. But even with code I dont know exactly how they do it. Can anyone give me more Informations?